# Error when trying to start plex

Tags: plex

When running:

```
sudo service plexmediaserver start
```

I receive this error:

```
~$ sudo service plexmediaserver start
Job for plexmediaserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status plexmediaserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Here is the output for the systemctl status

```
● plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server for Linux
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; vendor 
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2017-02-12 22:01:21 GMT
  Process: 3231 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_AP

Feb 12 22:01:16 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server for Linux.
Feb 12 22:01:16 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Unit entered failed
Feb 12 22:01:16 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 
Feb 12 22:01:21 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off ti
Feb 12 22:01:21 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server for Linux.
Feb 12 22:01:21 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repea
Feb 12 22:01:21 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server for Linux.
```

Here is the output for journalctl -xe

```
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plexmediaserver.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Feb 12 22:01:16 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Unit entered failed
Feb 12 22:01:16 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 
Feb 12 22:01:21 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Service hold-off ti
Feb 12 22:01:21 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server for Linux.
-- Subject: Unit plexmediaserver.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plexmediaserver.service has finished shutting down.
Feb 12 22:01:21 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repea
Feb 12 22:01:21 UBUN2LP systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server for Linux.
-- Subject: Unit plexmediaserver.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit plexmediaserver.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
```

I have tried re installing but receive this error every time.

I have also followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766485/how-to-set-up-plexmediaserver-in-ubuntu-16-04) and it made no difference.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in this comment? http://askubuntu.com/questions/766485/how-to-set-up-plexmediaserver-in-ubuntu-16-04#comment1308302_770661

Comment: Here's what i get back from that, same error:

`ntuser@UBUN2LP:~$ sudo systemctl --system daemon-reload && sudo service plexmediaserver start
Job for plexmediaserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status plexmediaserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

ntuser@UBUN2LP:~$`

Answer (score 0):

**I wrote myself a little guide based on info that actually worked for me online. Hopefully it can help someone.**

- INSTALL PLEX

CREATE 'PLEX' FOLDER UNDRE PRIMARY USER E.G /home/ntuser/PLEX

WHEN ADDING LIBARY TO PLEX ADD UP TO .../.../PLEX

Install Plex Media Server Ubuntu 16.x and Later

Add the Plex repository GPG key and add Plex the plex repository, you can copy and paste the whole block into your SSH session

If you get the key is not found error then it may have changed name, find the .key file from here and replace it in the wget line

```
wget -O - http://shell.ninthgate.se/packages/shell.ninthgate.se.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://shell.ninthgate.se/packages/debian jessie main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plex.list

sudo apt update
```

Install the Plex Media Server on Ubuntu 16.x and later

```
sudo apt install plexmediaserver -y
```

**YOU HAVE TO INSTALL .DEB MANUALLY!!!! SEE INSTALL DKPG INSTALL**

See if you can connect at http://ip.address:32400/web or http://ip.address:32400/manage/index.html#!/setup

Plex Media Server will autostart on boot ??

- Fix Plex Permission Issues

If you are getting permission issues it is because Plex runs as its own user, there are two options: change permissions of the downloads folders or change the user Plex runs as – you can do both but option 1 should suffice.

If Plex isn’t showing your folder so you can add you videos then this will fix it.

To change permissions of your media folders, first add the plex user to your main user’s group

```
sudo usermod -aG ntuser plex
```

Then set the permissions of your media folders to 775 so your group (and the plex user member of that group) can execute files

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /path/to/media
```